# Is there a way to only add verified email addresses to Firebase authentication console (React JS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a Firebase authentication system in my React web app. I know how to register an account and I know how to send a verification email out. Upon registration it sends the verification email which is fine, but the account gets added to the Firebase console database before the user has even verified it. I want it to be such that only verified accounts are added to the database.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import './join.css'
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, sendEmailVerification } from "firebase/auth"

export default function Join() {
    const [registerEmail, setRegisterEmail] = useState('');
    const [registerPassword, setRegisterPassword] = useState('');
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const verificationMessage = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
            setUser(currentUser);
        });

    }, [])
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const register = async () => {
        try {
            const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, registerEmail, registerPassword);
            console.log(user);
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        if (registerPassword === confirmPassword) {

            sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser);
            verificationMessage.current.style.display = 'block';
            register();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            alert('Passwords do not match, please try again!');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className="signup-div">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <fieldset>
                    <label className='labels'>Email:</label><br />
                    <input placeholder='Please enter your email' type="email" value={registerEmail} onChange={e => setRegisterEmail(e.target.value)} required />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label className='labels'>Set Password:</label><br />
                    <input placeholder='Create password' type="password" value={registerPassword} onChange={e => setRegisterPassword(e.target.value)} required />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <label className='labels'>Re-type password to confirm:</label><br />
                    <input placeholder="Confirm password" type="password" value={confirmPassword} onChange={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)} required />
                </fieldset>
                <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
            <div>
                Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div className='verification-message' ref={verificationMessage}>Welcome aboard! Please check your inbox and click the link in our verification email to verify your account. This could take upto a few minutes to arrive.</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: There is no way to prevent a user from signing in to Firebase until they have verified their email address. In fact, they need to be signed in to Firebase to request the email verification.

Comment: Call register only *after* the user confirmed the verification email and not directly after just having it sent?

Comment: So what's the point of the email verification feature then? Or is there a filter in Firebase that lets me only see verified users?

Comment: @derpirscher Yeah I was thinking that too but not sure how that's codeable?